# In HTML ng-value doesn't update according to the controller updated.bt at the same time expression is updated according to the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In HTML `ng-value="itemdetails[0].Title"` doesn't update according to the controller update.bt at the same time `{{itemdetails[0].Title}}` this expression is updated.I cannot understand what is the problem.

HTML

```
 <div id="lineitemmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Title</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="item.Title" class="form-control" ng-value="itemdetails[0].Title" placeholder="Title">
                            {{itemdetails[0].Title}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >SKU</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="item.SKU" class="form-control" ng-value="itemdetails[0].SKU" placeholder="SKU">
                            {{itemdetails[0].SKU}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Description</label>
                            <input type="textarea" ng-model="item.Description" class="form-control" ng-value="itemdetails[0].Description" placeholder="Description">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Unit type</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="item.UnitType" class="form-control" ng-value="itemdetails[0].UnitType" placeholder="Unit type">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Unit price</label>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="item.Unitprice" class="form-control" ng-value="itemdetails[0].Unitprice" placeholder="Unit price">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right: 75%" ng-click="saveitem(item)" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
app.angular.controller('lineItemController', function ($scope, rest, $window) {
$scope.lineitems = [];
$scope.itemdetails = [];
var currentitem;

$scope.addnewitem = function () {
    $scope.lineitems.push({Title:'Title',SKU:'SKU',Description:'Description',UnitType:'Unit type',UnitPrice:'Unit price'});


};

$scope.getitems = function () {
    rest.get('lineitem').then(function (results) {
        $scope.lineitems = [];
        $scope.itemdetails = [];
        $scope.lineitems = results;
        console.log(results);

    });
};

$scope.getitems();

$scope.showitem = function (item) {
    $scope.itemdetails.push(item);
    console.log($scope.itemdetails);

    $("#lineitemmodal").modal('show');
};

$scope.saveitem = function (newitem) {
    console.log($scope.itemdetails[0]);

    //item.ID = $scope.itemdetails.ID;
    $scope.itemdetails[0].Title = newitem.Title;
    $scope.itemdetails[0].SKU = newitem.SKU;
    $scope.itemdetails[0].Description = newitem.Description;
    $scope.itemdetails[0].UnitType = newitem.UnitType;
    $scope.itemdetails[0].Unitprice = newitem.Unitprice;

    rest.post('lineitem', {
        LineItem: $scope.itemdetails[0]
    }).then(function (results) {
        console.log(results);
        $scope.getitems();
    });
```

};

});

Comment: Are you supposed to have both `ng-model` and `ng-value`?

Comment: try to read more about https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue
it say that 'Binds the given expression to the value of <option> or input[radio], so that when the element is selected, the ngModel of that element is set to the bound value.'

Comment: yes.I need ng-model to collect the data

Comment: for input type=text you don't need to add ng-value. it will store on your model.

Comment: Yes, you need `ng-model` to collect the data, but what do you need `ng-value` for?

Comment: i used `ng-value` to show the value of relevant object.I have an  array of objects.I used `ng-repeat` to loop the array.and when I click on a element in `ng-repeat` I need to show full datails of that Object.In that case I used `ng-value`